# Generalized Heisenberg algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, physics, mathematical-physics

How Generalized Heisenberg algebras have been involved in Physics? Or better to say where (generalized) Heisenberg algebras are applicable in Physics? Can you please explain it to me? I want to know it from a mathematician's point of view.

Thanks!

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_physics_and_representation_theory#The_Heisenberg_case), section "The Heisenberg case".

Comment: @DietrichBurde Many thanks! Sorry, what is the relation between Heisenberg group and Heisenberg algebra?

Comment: The Lie algebra of the Heisenberg Lie group is the Heisenberg Lie algebra. See also "Lie algebras versus Lie groups" in the above wikipedia article.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry, what people mean by Heisenberg algebra is the Heisenberg Lie algebra? There is no other Heisenberg algebra? Thanks!